# How do I replace all occurrences in an array with another array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to replace all occurrences in an array (string) with another array.

I have a code that: 
stores the string in an array in which the replacing is to take place `output[]`,
another array that stores the string to be searched for as `replace[]` and a third array called `toBeReplacedBy` and the replacing of the first occurrence works just fine but it skips the other occurrences in the `output`

for example:

```
replace[]:

abc


toBeReplacedBy[]:

xyz 

output[]:

abcdefabc

becomes
xyzdefabc


but it should become:
xyzdefxyz
```

I suspect the problem lies with the replacer code :

```
    //the replacer
    for (i = 0; i<80; i++) {
        if (output[i] == replace[i])
            output[i] = toBeReplacedBy[i];
    }

    //debug purpose

    puts("output[]:\n");
    puts(output);


    return 0;
}
```

What have I done wrong here and how could I get it to replace all occurrences in the array.

please be aware that I only wish to use `stdio.h` to do this

thabks in advance

Comment: How many `char *` subscripts are there in `replace` and `toBeReplacedBy`? If they are single arrays of char, then you should put `output[i] = toBeReplacedBy`. Similarly, you should be checking `output[i] == replace` to see if the pointers are equal. Now, if you're looking to compare the contents of the arrays, you'll need `string.h` and strncmp.

Comment: wouldnt your arrays overflow, if there are more than 3 matches?

Comment: There is not enough here for us to answer your question (e.g. the function declaration is missing). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: First, it matters if `toBeReplacedBy` is always the same size as `replace` or not. This greatly affects what algorithm can be used. Second, your current code checks each character individually when deciding whether to replace it. That cannot work properly. You must find the **entire string** in the source and then replace that. You will need to think about how to compare `replace` with an arbitrary position in the source string. That said, this looks like a homework assignment you are not well prepared for. The proper approach is to pay attention in class and work along with the lessons.

Comment: This example seems completely arbitrary but doesn't provide enough information about the boundaries of the solution. Are 'abc' and 'xyz' substrings to be replaced as a whole? Or is every instance of 'a' meant to be replaced by 'x', regardless of order. You have a length of 80 in your loop but your example output array is much shorter. We need a lot more information to provide an adequate solution.

Answer (score 2):

Never iterate further than the array length. This leads to undefined and possibly dangerous behaviour. If you only expect strings, use something like:

```
int i = 0; 
while(output[i] != '\0')
{
    // your logic here
    i++;
}
```

Additionally you want to check for concurrent appearances of the same characters. But in your code you only check the first three characters. Everything after that is undefinded behaviour, because you cannot know what `replace[3]` returns.

Something similar to this could work:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k;
while(output[i] != '\0')
{
    if (output[i] == replace[j])
        j++;
    else
        j = 0;
    // replace 3 with the array length of the replace[] array
    if (j == 3)
    {
        for(k = i; j >= 0; k-- )
        {
            output[k] = toBeReplacedBy[j]
            j--
        }
        j = 0;
    }
    i++;
}
```

But please check the array boundaries.

edit: Additionally as Nellie states using a debugger would help you to understand what went wrong. Go through your program step by step and look how and when values change.

Answer (score 0):

First advice is to try to debug your program if it does not work.

```
for (i = 0; i<80; i++) {
        if (output[i] == replace[i])
            output[i] = toBeReplacedBy[i];
    }
```

There are two problems in this loop.

The first is that are iterating until `i` is 80. Let's look what happens when `i` becomes 3. `output[3]` in case of *abcdefabc* is *d*, but what is `replace[3]`? Your replacement array had only 3 letters, so you have to go back in the replacement array once you finish with one occurrence of it in the original string.

The second is that you check letter by letter.

Say you original array, which you named `output` somehow was *abkdefabc*, first three letters do not match your replacement string, but you will check the first two letters they will match with the replacement's first two letters and you will incorrectly change them.

So you need to first check that the whole replacement string is there and only then replace.

Answer (score 0):

You should use strlen() to know length of your array or iterate until you reach the end of a your array ('\0').

'\0' and strlen are only available for array of char.

Your loop should looks like this :

```
int i = 0;
int len = strlen(my_string);
while (i < len)
{
  //logic here
  i = i + 1;
}
```

OR

```
int i = 0;
while (my_string[i] != '\0')
{
  // logic here
  i = i + 1;
}
```